# Test Case Oracle Select for error

Tags: oracle, select, testing, testcase

I need to make some test cases for Oracle packages. 
I have a package which has store procedures, some of them are selects. Each Store procedure has"Exception" (try - catch)
My question is: 
**How Can i provoke an error when calling a store procedure that only contains a "select" ?** any suggestion?

thanks all in advance ..

Comment: Will any error do? Or do you want specific errors to be thrown for different test cases? Please include more details as currently the question is very vague.

Comment: You may want to check [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i1871) ... and please post your simplified code - a **procedure can't contain only select**, there must be at least a BEGIN - END block.

Answer (score 0):

Drop or rename the tables which are being accessed by the `SELECT` using

```
DROP TABLE YOUR_TABLE
```

or

```
RENAME YOUR_TABLE TO YOUR_RENAMED_TABLE
```

Best of luck.